# Azure DevOps teams into custom fields with some rules

Tags: azure, azure-devops, agile, servicenow

In my team area, I created two teams. I want to add those teams into the custom fields in work items.

Could anyone help me to resolve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean add 'teams into customer fields'? What do you want the work item to do? Could you please share us your customer fields to us?
And do you mean you want the team members to show in the work item?

Comment: Through team configuration we can create teams right? Under workitems, I created a custom field called Agile Teams and in that field, I want to display all those teams I created through team configuration( It is also displayed in Area).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this function is not support for now.
You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) site, which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggesting raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team will provide the updates if they view it.